# Different RAM models, same brand

Tags: laptop, memory

i'm trying to upgrade my laptop RAM capacity.

I use an 2 years old **ACER ASPIRE VX15** with a 8GB RAM module **KINGSTON ACR24D4S7S8MB-8** (8GB DDR4 PC4-19200 2400MHz 1rx8 1.2v NON-ECC 260-pin SO-DIMM).

My question is: Is it a good idea to buy the **Crucial CT8G4SFS824A** (8GB DDR4 PC4-19200 2400MHz 1rx8 260-pin SO-DIMM) to add it to my laptop so i'll have 16GB of RAM?

Or should i instead buy the **KINGSTON KVR24S17S8** (8GB DDR4 PC4-19200 2400MHz CL17 1.2v NON-ECC 260-pin SO-DIMM) knowing that i can't get it yet for a long time?

And is it even possible to use 4GB instead of 8 GB?
Of course i'm asking in case they don't match and lead to crashes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the specs match as you indicate, you'll be fine. Don't do a half upgrade; they need to be the same capacity to get [dual channel](https://www.slashgear.com/acer-aspire-vx-15-keeps-the-ports-stays-unique-for-gamers-03469681/).

It [does not look like a trivial upgrade](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tpJLxvViH-g) as you have to remove the entire bottom panel. You might consider finding a local shop to do the upgrade. Good luck!

Comment: So what about brands? Can i use CRUSIAL with KINGSTON without a problem or do i have imperatively to use KINGSTON for both?

Comment: You do not have to match brands. Looking at the specs on the manufacturers respective web sites, these have the same form factor (SODIMM), speed (DDR4-2400), latency (17 cycles), and timings (17-17-17). Even without that perfect match, many memory modules will work together with a lowest common denominator. You will not have a problem.